# Can I set a cell in a sheet as the selected one, without activating the sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

In a workbook I am creating I have created a procedure which loops through several worksheets clearing out some ranges++, preparing the workbook for a new year. However, I wanted to set a given cell in the sheet, e.g. `F5` as the active one before moving on to the next sheet, as that's where it's most likely the users will start inputting data when they move to the sheet.

However, trying to put both `.Select` and `.Activate` into line 5 of the code below fails with `Select / Activate method of Range class failed`.

```
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(1, ws.CodeName, "Veke_", vbTextCompare) > 0 And Len(ws.CodeName) = 7 Then
      Call lås_opp_ark(ws)
      Call oppdater_ark_for_nytt_år(ws, førsteSkiftIVeka(dato))
      ws.Range("F5").Select
      Call lås_ark(ws)
    End If
  Next ws
```

Trying to figure out why this didn't work I eventually came across [this documentation-page from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221576%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which states that:

> Before you can use the Selection property successfully, you must activate a workbook, activate or select a sheet, and then select a range (or other object) using the Select method.

Which I take to mean that using `Select` on anything but the active worksheet won't work. The page doesn't explicitly state anything about `Activate`, but I assume the reasons for the errors I'm getting to be the same.

Now, my question is this - is there any way to set the active cell in a nonactive worksheet without activating it first? If not, would activating each sheet in the workbook to set the active cell be very resource intensive? I guess I could check the latter myself, but any input would be interesting too.

Comment: No - you have to activate each sheet.

Comment: @Rory Darn. Well, I guess that's what I'll go with, then =/

Comment: if you don't want to activate each sheet in the middle of your loop. You could always write more code after your loop is finished that sets the active cell in each sheet after your first loop. That will run very quickly at the end and not throw off your loop. You can loop through each `ws` and use the answer provided by @EEM.

Answer (score 1):

No need to `select` the cell, instead activate it. Try this:

Replace:

```
ws.Range("F5").Select
```

with this:

```
  Application.Goto ws.Cells(1), 1   'This activates ws and scrolls to place cell `A1` at the top of the window
  Application.Goto ws.Range("F5")   'This selects Cell `F5`
```

see [Application.Goto Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839232.aspx)

Comment: Hmm, I suppose it saves me a line of code over using `Activate`, but unless I read the documentation wrong this also activates the worksheet?

Comment: Absolutely, It activates the worksheet (never say it would not). The different is that allows you to scroll the window and nicely place the cell you want to show the users in a friendly display. Try with a cell like `AA100` using select and you'll see the difference.